# Criar query com intervalo de datas no doctrine 2.0

Tags: php, sql, symfony-2, doctrine-2

Estou tentando obter os registros que tem como processadoEm(DateTime) inferior a 2 dias da data atual.

Estou partindo do seguinte raciocínio.

```
  public function obtemSolicitacoesAntigasParaDeletar($executar = true){

    $qb = $this->buscar(array(), false);

    $qb->Where('sol.processadoEm < :data');

    $params[':data'] = 'CURRENT_DATE() - INTERVAL 2 DAY';
    $qb->setParameters($params);

    return $executar === true ? $qb->getQuery()->getResult() : $qb;
}
```

Mas estou percebendo que não está funcionando de acordo, ele me retorna registro que não satisfazem essa restrição.

No command do SQL funciona essa Query, porem no doctrine não está. 
Alguem pode me ajudar a ajustar esse metodo?

Att. Felipe.

Answer (score 0):

Dae galera.

Bom, encontrei uma maneira de realizar essa tarefa.

a solução encontrada foi:

```
public function obtemSolicitacoesAntigasParaDeletar($executar = true){

    $dataAtual = new DateTime('now');
    $dataAtual->sub(new \DateInterval('P1D'));

    $qb = $this->buscar(array(), false);

    $qb->andWhere('sol.processadoEm < :data');

    $params[':data'] = $dataAtual;
    $qb->setParameters($params);

    return $executar === true ? $qb->getQuery()->getResult() : $qb;
}
```

Podem fechar o topido.

Vlw.

Comment: Não existe o conceito de "fechar tópico" aqui. É você quem tem que validar a sua própria resposta.